# IPython Interactive Matplotlib Widgets Remote Server?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am running an ipython server (for the notebook) on a remote linux machine.  I have setup a profile that listens on the remote machine such that I can access locally using:

```
https://myserver:9999
```

This launches the standard IPython notebook interface that you would expect to see (after authentication).  Everything works as expected.

Recently I have started using matplotlib widgets.  These do not work in the notebook if using inline plots (the server just ships pngs).  The simple fix on a local machine is to use `ipython notebook --pylab` and omit `--inline`.

In my IPython notebook profile I have commented out:

```
#c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'
```

and I launch with `ipython notebook --pylab`.

Login still works as expected, but if I use the `%pylab` magic to get started the kernel dies.

EDIT: The `%pylab` magic is redundant if I launch with `--pylab`

Is it possible to attain interactivity by not using inline plots in a remote login environment like this?  I imagine that I need to tell the server that it is forwarding not only the port 9999 ipython data, but also needs to be forwarding X.  Any insight appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit2: Crap....got it - my XServer on the local box had died....I can report that this functions as expected as long as you actually have a live XServer locally...crap.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem.  You should write up your edit2 as an answer (and accept it when it will let you).